# Can't update in database data. Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a small problem with my Controller action. I can't update my "link" in Database, bt `dd` method work is correctly when I'm try to check data.

Form

```
<form class="col-lg-push-6" action="/admin/links/{{$link->id}}/update" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                <label class="bmd-label-floating">New Link Value</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="100" name="value">
                <button  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'value' => 'required'
    ]);

    $link=RedirectUrl::AllLinks()->where('id', $id);
    $link->value = $request->input('value');

    



    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Link Updated!');
  }
```

Model

```
 public function scopeAllLinks($query){

    return $query->get();

}
```

Route

```
Route::prefix('admin')->middleware('auth')->group(function(){
Route::get('/', 'Admin\IndexController@index');
Route::get('dashboard', 'Admin\IndexController@index')->name('dashboard');
Route::get('links', 'Admin\LinkController@index')->name('links');
Route::get('links/{id}', 'Admin\LinkController@linkById');
Route::post('links/{id}/update', 'Admin\LinkController@update');

});
```

Comment: You never save it.

Comment: @aynber what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Read https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#updates : First, you only use `where`, so `$link` is a query builder object, not a single model. And you never save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things here:

1. Your `scopeAllLinks` scope is incorrect, you don't call `get` inside a scope, instead you return the query builder instance.
2. You can use `find` since you're passing in a record id:

   `$link = RedirectUrl::find($id);`
3. You never call save or update on the record:

   `$link->value = $request->input('value');`

   `$link->save(); // <--- add this`